# javascript generated dynamic table and function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a JavaScript generated table that displays the results of a regex. I am calling a function to enable a cell to be populated `(getTaqman())`:

```
 while (snps != null)
       {
            rs_val = snps[0];
            html+="<tr>";
            html+="<td> "+rs_val+" </td>";
            html+="<td><span id="+rs_val+"> loading... </span></td>";
            html+="</tr>";
            getTaqman(rs_val);
            snps = regex.exec(str);
      };
```

An example of a table generated:

```
rs275651    C__32407245_40

rs5182      C__32407245_40

rs12050217  C__32407245_40
```

The left column is populated correctly. Also, the span id is correctly defined (not shown), however the result of the function is correct only for the first row and after that it is the the same for the rest of the rows.

Here is the function definition:

```
function getTaqman(rs_val) 
        {
            let url = `imparter.php?PMID=${rs_val}`
            $.ajax(
                  {
                    url: url,
                    success: function(result)
                      { 

                       console.log(rs_val);

                       $("#"+rs_val).html(result);                               

                      }
                  });
        };
```

Why would the function only work for the first row?

** I also tried setting async to true. When I did that none of the second column cells were populated

Comment: Not enough information please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Can you show the content of `result`?

Comment: Also note that when you call `getTaqman`, the HTML element on which it is supposed to work, is not created yet.

Comment: @ Blaze: the HTML span element is created, it just works only on the first row which is strange as each row has a different span id

Comment: @ Blaze: the content of result is a the series of strings starting with 'rs' as per the table example

Comment: I suspect this is something that could be addressed with having the loop waiting on the callback return value -- any suggestions?